# Nav Drawer with Navigation Items and normal Items

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-components

I have a Nav Drawer with a few items that I use with the new Navigation Architecture Component to navigate to different fragments.
Now I have one item that should trigger an action (no navigation) but since the NavigationUI is already using the NavigationItemSelectedListener I can't add a second one.

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, findNavController(navHostFragment))
```

How can I handle the click of items that dont "navigate".

This seems to work without breaking the navigation:

```
navView.menu[3].setOnMenuItemClickListener
```

Comment: can you please add the code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an item with action but without layout, you can add your item to **activity_main_drawer.xml** file as below.

```
     <item android:id="@+id/nav_test"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_test"
            android:title="Test" />
```

and in **MainActivity.kt** you can find item based on its id and set clickListener

```
 navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_test).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "nav test clicked")
            return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
        }
```

PS: Do not need to add the action/layout or item to **mobile_navigation.xml** file.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**You don't puted your code here, for this, I presume that** you have an implementation of `NavigationItemSelectedListener` on your `Activity`. If yes, try pass the listener on your `navView` as follow:

instead it:

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

try it:

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            //use just itens that "navigate"
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Try update your ask with some code

Comment: Im using setupWithNavController. (Added the code above)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I use `navigationView.menu.getItem(3).setOnMenuItemClickListener` or `navigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete_and_load).setOnMenuItemClickListener`